# When I print my code I don't want ".." to print yet

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return

Is there a way that I still get the ".." further in the code, but don't have ".." till after "1+"

eg. n = 2
*my code at the moment will output

..1+..1+2+..

*i want my code to output

1+..1+2+..

```
def nested_increasing_additions(n):
    ans = ""
    n = n + 1
    for i in range(1,(n+1)):
        for k in range(1,i):
            ans = ans + str(k) + "+"

        ans = ans + ".."

    return ans 
print(nested_increasing_additions(1))
```

Comment: I suggest you write **in words** the steps you need to take to build up the string. This will help you clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `..` **only** if `ans` is not empty:

```
def nested_increasing_additions(n):
    ans = ""
    n = n + 1
    for i in range(1,(n+1)):
        for k in range(1,i):
            ans = ans + str(k) + "+"

        if ans:
            ans = ans + ".."

    return ans 
print(nested_increasing_additions(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want it as below, i tested your code from the post it print

..1+..

```
def nested_increasing_additions(n):
    ans = ""
    for i in range(1,(n+2)):
        for k in range(1,i+1):
            ans = ans + str(k) + "+"    
        ans = ans + ".."
    return ans 

print(nested_increasing_additions(1))
# 1+..1+2+..
```